# What does this symbol mean in graph theory ≤P?

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity, polynomial-math

In this case the p is supposed to be a subscript. Is it supposed to mean less than or equal polynomial time?

Comment: I'm trying to show that a directed hamilton cycle  ≤P undirected hamilton cycle

Comment: This is most likely defined in your textbook. Start going through pages in reverse order from where you saw this symbol until you find the definition.

Answer (score 3):

A ≤<sub>p</sub> B means that there is a [polynomial-time many-one reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_reduction) from A to B, i.e., there exists a polynomial-time computable function f such that, for every string x, we have x in A if and only if f(x) in B.